# How to update a specific column and row with a trigger in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, database-trigger

So I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DailyParkReport] (
[Id]                  INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Date]                DATE       NOT NULL,
[InchesPrecipitation] FLOAT (53) NOT NULL,
[NumVisitors]         INT        NOT NULL,
[Rainout]             BIT        NOT NULL,
[Temperature]         FLOAT (53) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_DailyParkReport] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

and I want to set up a trigger for whenever the `InchesPrecipitation` is greater than 4 it makes the `Rainout` value 1 meaning true and if the `InchesPrecipitation` is < 4 then it makes the Rainout value 0. All of this should update the row in the same table.

What I have for the trigger so far is:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_weather_ForInsertUpdate 
ON [dbo].[DailyParkReport]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    IF (Select InchesPrecipitation FROM INSERTED) > 4

    UPDATE DailyParkReport
    SET Rainout = 1
    WHERE Rainout = 0

    ELSE

    UPDATE DailyParkReport
    SET Rainout = 0
    WHERE Rainout = 1

END
```

The problem I'm running into is that whenever the trigger fires it updates every single row in the table and I only want it to update that specific row.

I have fixed the problem by  updating my trigger to the following

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_weather_ForInsertUpdate 
ON [dbo].[DailyParkReport]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON
IF (Select InchesPercipitation FROM INSERTED) > 4

    UPDATE d SET Rainout = 1
    FROM dbo.DailyParkReport AS d
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE Id = d.Id)

ELSE

    UPDATE d SET Rainout = 0
    FROM dbo.DailyParkReport AS d
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE Id = d.Id)

END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017)... it seems to be a decent fit here. It does have it's draw backs, of course.

```
create table #DailyParkReport 
([Id]                 INT        IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[Date]                DATE       NOT NULL,
[InchesPrecipitation] FLOAT (53) NOT NULL,
[NumVisitors]         INT        NOT NULL,
[Rainout]             as case when [InchesPrecipitation] >= 4 then 1 else 0 end,
[Temperature]         FLOAT (53) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_DailyParkReport] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC))

GO


insert into #DailyParkReport
values
(getdate(),3,1,98.6)
,(getdate(),5,1,98.6)

select * from #DailyParkReport

update #DailyParkReport
set InchesPrecipitation = 6 where Id = 1

select * from #DailyParkReport

drop table #DailyParkReport
```

Comment: Think more like the great Lange every day!

Comment: WOW. Truly humbled by that.

Comment: The thing is i have to use a trigger for my project so i wanted to use a trigger. I have gotten it to work by changing it to this.


    UPDATE d SET Rainout = 1
    FROM dbo.DailyParkReport AS d
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE Id = d.Id)

Comment: I am confused by your comment @DanielJiwani and think you meant to edit your original question, perhaps?

Comment: I see, @DanielJiwani, but you do understand this is a longer, and more expensive route of accomplishing the same thing correct? While it may work, the best solution for this would be a computed column.

Comment: I don't know much about the computed column but I'll take your word on it for it being a better solution. I just had to make 2 triggers for a web application i am working on for school and My professor liked the idea of having a trigger related to the weather somehow.

Comment: Perhaps the computed column will set you apart from the other students :) @DanielJiwani

Comment: Sigh....this is why education is so poor. The professors come up with bizarre contrived examples and make decision about implementation that are not great. What they should really do is teach you about triggers and computed columns, then define a problem but not define the path you have to take. That lets the student make some decisions and teaches them how it is in the real world.

Comment: Yeah I totally agree. This professor gave us a project worth 40% of our grade without any insight or guidance about asp.net or javascript and teaches the very minimal about database and sql.

Comment: @DanielJiwani I feel your pain. Hopefully your next professor will have a bit better handle on how to teach the concepts needed to succeed.

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr_weather_ForInsertUpdate
ON [dbo].[DailyParkReport]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    UPDATE DailyParkReport
        SET Rainout = CASE WHEN i.InchesPrecipitation >= 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM
        DailyParkReport a
        INNER JOIN inserted i ON i.Id = a.Id
END
```

Comment: This won't work. You can't just reference inserted. You would need a join.

Comment: @SeanLange Edited using join.

Comment: There are some real challenges here. You have a cross join now so it will still update every row in DailyParkReport.This also assumes there is only 1 row ever in inserted which is not safe. And this could be done with a single update statement with a couple of case expressions. But really, a computed column is the better approach.

Comment: @SeanLange Edited using inner join.